# How to pass a github secret to asp.net core app deployed using github action?

Tags: asp.net-core, github, github-actions

I want to use GitHub secrets inside the repository code.
The repository is an asp.net core web app. I am deploying the app to the Azure app service using Github actions.

I have tried declaring env variable in the workflow like this

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134798
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135048

name: Azure App Service - TestJuzer(Production), Build and deploy DotnetCore app

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  TEST_STRING: ${{ secrets.TEST_STRING }}

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    
    steps:
    # checkout the repo
    - name: 'Checkout Github Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Set up Node.js '12.x'
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12.x'

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '5.0.x'

    - name: Build with dotnet
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release
      env:
        TEST_STRING: ${{ secrets.TEST_STRING }}

    - name: dotnet publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
      

    - name: Run Azure webapp deploy action using publish profile credentials
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: TestJuzer
        slot-name: Production
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_461CFB6B8D42419FA7F58944D621BA78 }}
        package: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
      env:
        TEST_STRING: ${{ secrets.TEST_STRING }}
```

and accessing the env variable in .net like this

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_STRING")
```

"TEST_STRING" is the name of the secret. But I am getting null.

I want to pass secret as an environment variable in the workflow and use it in the deployed app.

Any help appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You set env variable on agent machine. And here you should rather set it on App Service. You could use [Azure App Service Settings](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-app-service-settings):

Here is sample workflow:

```yaml
# .github/workflows/configureAppSettings.yml
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: '${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}'
    - uses: azure/appservice-settings@v1
      with:
        app-name: 'my-app'
        slot-name: 'staging'  # Optional and needed only if the settings have to be configured on the specific deployment slot
        app-settings-json: '${{ secrets.APP_SETTINGS }}' 
        connection-strings-json: '${{ secrets.CONNECTION_STRINGS }}'
        general-settings-json: '{"alwaysOn": "false", "webSocketsEnabled": "true"}' #'General configuration settings as Key Value pairs'
      id: settings
    - run: echo "The webapp-url is ${{ steps.settings.outputs.webapp-url }}"
    - run: |
        az logout
```

In you case it could be like:

```yaml
    - name: Set Web App settings
      uses: Azure/appservice-settings@v1
      with:
       app-name: 'node-rnc'
       app-settings-json: |
         [
             {
                 "name": "TEST_STRING",
                 "value": "${{ secrets.TEST_STRING }}",
                 "slotSetting": false
             }
         ]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but still getting null. How to access this app-settings-json contents in .net core app?

Comment: You should have it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

Comment: I tried accessing it with IConfiguration. But that did not work as well. I did not know about Application Settings in the Azure App service. I am using that now as it serves the same purpose for me. For future reference on how to access app service settings in .net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-dotnetcore?pivots=platform-linux#access-environment-variables